# What exactly happens with QTimer start function?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code:

**mytimer.cpp**

```
#include "mytimer.h"
#include <QtCore>
MyTimer::MyTimer()
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(mySlot()));
    timer->start(1000);    
}

void MyTimer::mySlot()
{
    qDebug()<<"timer executed";

}
```

and in the **main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "mytimer.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyTimer mtimer;
    qDebug()<<"DONE";

    return a.exec();
}
```

Now the output comes as:

```
DONE
timer executed
timer executed
...
...
...
...
infinite sequence
```

I am really confused by this. How is that we are done with our main function and still the code for the `SLOT mySlot()` is getting executed?

What are the important aspects to this? that I need to understand?

Also what changes occurs when I modify **mytimer.cpp** MyTimer() to:

```
MyTimer::MyTimer()
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    QEventLoop eventloop;
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(mySlot()));
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),&eventloop,SLOT(quit()));
    timer->start(1000);
    eventloop.exec();
}
```

There is one **timer executed** just before **DONE** is printed. To Be specific the output now becomes:

```
timer executed
DONE
timer executed
timer executed
...
...
...
...
infinite sequence
```

What caused that separate **timer executed** to appear above the **DONE**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - your main function is not done. It called a.exec() which will never return in your application.

a.exec() in turn processes a "message queue" which triggers all the timer events that call mySlot().

Comment: Gah! 7 seconds too late! If one of ours has to be the answer choose this one :)

Comment: @VictorTran: Your answer is a little more Qt centric - I would choose yours. ;-) You may just add a comment regarding relationship of QTimer and event loop.

Comment: @VictorTran Could you please see my edited question.

Comment: @SumeetSingh ```eventloop.exec()``` blocks until the ```quit()``` slot is called. Therefore, when the exec() function is called, the function doesn't return just yet. When the timer fires, it calls the quit() slot, allowing execution to continue and go back to the main() function. :)

Answer (score 4):

`a.exec` starts the event loop. It doesn't return a value until either `QApplication::exit()` or `QApplication::quit()` or all windows are closed.

Comment: @SumeetSingh I replied to you on another comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

> What caused that separate timer executed to appear above the DONE?

The timer signals are **always** emitted from within the outermost event loop - because that's where the locus of control is (i.e. that's where the thread is running - it's inside Qt). Since you spun a local event loop (`eventloop.exec();`), that's where the timer invocation came from. As soon as that event loop was done and that `exec()` had returned, the `MyTimer` constructor had exited, `DONE` was printed out, and remaining timer invocations happen from the main event loop.

Generally speaking, code that nests event loops is broken, so if you ever find yourself with more than one `exec()` on the call stack, you're doing it wrong. There are a few notable exceptions: native dialogs on OS X require their own nested event loop due to OS X API deficiencies, and `QDrag` requires `exec()` also most likely due to platform deficiencies that require an `exec()` for portability, even if on some platforms it'd be unnecessary.